# Is it possible to use Lab color space to segment certain colors?

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation, hsv, cielab

I know that the easiest way to segment certain color is using the HSV color space, but I have a task to do it in HSV, RGB and Lab...
I am really confused how to do it in Lab. I did it in HSV and it's really simple.
Here's the function that segments human color using the HSV color space

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def HSV_Segmentation(image):
    lowerRange= np.array([0, 70, 0] , dtype="uint8")
    upperRange= np.array([25, 255, 255], dtype="uint8")
    mask = image[:].copy()

    imageHSV = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    imageRange = cv2.inRange(imageHSV,upperRange, lowerRange)

    mask[:,:,0] = imageRange
    mask[:,:,1] = imageRange
    mask[:,:,2] = imageRange

    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    faceHSV = cv2.bitwise_and(image,mask)
    
    return faceHSV
```

And now I'm stuck at Lab color space,and I am not really sure where to begin.
I tried something similar with upper and lower range of human color but obviously that's not the right way.

Comment: From Wikipedia "The CIELAB ...  expresses color as three values: L* for the lightness from black (0) to white (100), a* from green (−) to red (+), and b* from blue (−) to yellow (+). CIELAB was designed so that the same amount of numerical change in these values corresponds to roughly the same amount of visually perceived change." So the L is intensity and you have to look at the appropriate + or - values of A, B to find the color your want. A and B are often biased so that they are all positive. So you have to look at above and below 50%.

Comment: Experiment with http://colormine.org/convert/rgb-to-lab

Comment: The human color is known to be easier to segment in the HSV color space. You could transform the LAB to HSV or find a range in LAB where you can obtain similar results.

Comment: @JoOkuma Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: You can find some here (https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C39&q=HSV+segmentation+skin&btnG=)

Answer (score 1):

I tried different ranges but this seems to work for me.
That wasn't so hard :)

```
def Lab_Segmentation(image):
    lowerRange= np.array([0, 135, 135] , dtype="uint8")
    upperRange= np.array([255, 160, 195], dtype="uint8")
    mask = image[:].copy()

    imageLab = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
    imageRange = cv2.inRange(imageLab,lowerRange, upperRange)
    
    mask[:,:,0] = imageRange
    mask[:,:,1] = imageRange
    mask[:,:,2] = imageRange
    
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    faceLab = cv2.bitwise_and(image,mask)

    return faceLab
```